# Moved time zones now datetime.utcnow() is incorrect

Tags: python, datetime, time, google-calendar-api, pytz

I'm working on a Python application that fires notifications at certain times. I started working on this project in Italy and the program worked fine, but now that I'm back in the U.S., the time is completely wrong. There's a four hour time difference between the actual time and the time that is shown, which is weird, because Italy is 6 hours ahead.

For example, the time that datetime.utcnow() shows is 2016-05-10T18:55:47.920001Z but the time is actually 2016-05-10T14:55:47.920001Z

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
```

I tried using pytz to set the time zone (which gives me the correct time), but the API that I'm sending the current time to (Google Calendar), won't accept it. This time isn't accepted but the line of code above is, but the time is wrong.

```
eastern = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern).isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
```

How can I get datetime.datetime.utcnow() to reflect my current time?

Comment: Pat of the problem may be that you're using the `datetime` constructor to assign the `pytz` time zone - [according to the documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) that doesn't always work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# 'Z' indicates UTC time
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().isoformat() + 'Z'
print(now)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.utcnow()` returns time in UTC. It returns the exact same value wherever you are. UTC time is the same in Italy and in US.

To generate [rfc3339 timestamp](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6): `.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'` is correct.

`datetime.now(eastern).isoformat() + 'Z'` is wrong. Use just `datetime.now(eastern).isoformat()`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> eastern = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z', datetime.now(eastern).isoformat()
('2016-05-11T15:25:18.857833Z', '2016-05-11T11:25:18.857860-04:00')
```

Both return the same time (if we ignore microseconds). Today, 15:25UTC is the same time as 11:25 in New York:

```
<local time> == <utc time> + <utc offset>
   11:25     ==   15:25    +   (-04:00)
```